# A "Bad Egg" probability problem

Tags: probability

The problem, and my attempted work. The $1.34 note is the answer in the book. I can't find the error in my work.

[image]

I hoped to find a solution posted on line, and found:

[image]

Which was encouraging, as it seems to reflect my calculations, up to the arithmetic to get the total.

Note: This problem appears in 2 editions of Paul Foerster's work, "Algebra and Trigonometry" as well as "Precalculus and Trigonometry". Although, for the latter book, the new edition dropped the problem. Both old books contain the same offered solution. I am an in-house Math tutor, and am careful to declare an answer a "typo" in a book.

Edit: A kind member caught a foolish typo for me. FWIW - this is what I deal with every day, a student who gets the concept, runs the numbers, but a tiny arithmetic error results in a wrong answer. Coworkers vary on grading this. Some offer zero pts for the wrong answer, others, a fraction off for the source of the error. And it's always humbling when I do this in front of them. In a good way.

Comment: Why do you multiply by $\$2.00$ if all eggs are good?

Comment: Thanks! - Because his cost is 60 cents per dozen, sold for 1 dollar per dozen, 5 dozen eggs (times 40cents)  is 2 dollars  profit.

Comment: Your decimal point is out on the last set (2 bad eggs). It's 0.001695.

Comment: (Facepalm time) - damn. That was it. Thanks. At least this was on my own, not with the student when I started this.